# Laravel Application Environment variable in config/app.php and .env file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

In my config/app.php file, the app environment variable it set like this: `'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),`. Meanwhile in the .env file, the app environment is set to `APP_ENV=local`.

It appears as though only the .env file matters. The app behaves as though the environment is local.
`php artisan env` returns

```
Current application environment: local
```

Is there some instance when I should make modifications to the app.php file instead of the .env file?
Should the variables in the app file just be ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the docs 
[env second argument](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/configuration#retrieving-environment-configuration)

The second value passed to the env function is the "default value". This value will be used if no environment variable exists for the given key.
So you get value from te env file.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to use `.env` settings then simply commented out or remove them. By doing this, system will pick your defined values from the `config/app.php` file.

For example: `'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'YOUR ENVIRONMENT VALUE')`